# TestNG Default Report

Tags: report, testng

I have two requirement

1. Running testng suite from command line
2. Have a unique name for the default report(emailable report) which is generated by testng

How do i check that?

Answer (score 0):

1. Running TestNG suite from command line

From the [documentation](http://testng.org/doc/documentation-main.html#running-testng):

> java org.testng.TestNG testng1.xml [testng2.xml testng3.xml ...]

2. Have a unique name for the default report

The name of the emailable report is not configurable and will always be `emailable-report.html`.
But you can copy/paste [one](https://github.com/cbeust/testng/blob/master/src/main/java/org/testng/reporters/EmailableReporter.java) of [the 2](https://github.com/cbeust/testng/blob/master/src/main/java/org/testng/reporters/EmailableReporter2.java) email reporters, make the change and use your new own reporter.
Or even better, propose a fix on https://github.com/cbeust/testng/pulls and make the name configurable for everyone. 
A related issue is already opened: https://github.com/cbeust/testng/issues/1332

Comment: Can we change the location of the folder in which report is generated